# Display array data in horizontal order using smarty

Tags: php, smarty, sitemap

I'm unable to get the output in proper order so as to align it in this format as **apple.com/sitemap**. Problem I'm facing is it with  tags which is used while displaying the values, I'm unable to put it in proper place.

Right now, the output is:

```
<ul class= "sitemap">

</ul></li><li><h2>Parent 1</h2><ul>
<li>Sub Cat 1</li>
<li>Sub Cat 2</li>

</ul></li><li><h2>Parent 2</h2><ul>
<li>Sub Cat3</li>
<li>Sub Cat 4</li>
</ul></li><li><h2>Parent 3</a></h2><ul>
```

If you see the ul tag is not closing properly because of which I'm unable to implement CSS..

I have created table as:

```
id | parent | name | url  

1  |  0  | Parent1 | Link
2  |  1  | Sub Cat1| Link
3  |  2  | Sub Cat2| Link
4  |  0  | Parent2 | Link
```

MySQL Query to fetch the values:

```
$sql = 'SELECT parent,name, url FROM sitemap ORDER BY CASE WHEN parent =0 THEN id ELSE parent END , CASE WHEN parent =0 THEN 0 ELSE id END';
```

Lines to display the data on Page:

```
{foreach from=$sitemap item=c name=sitemap}

{ assign var="tmp" value= $c.parent  }
{ if $tmp==0}

</ul></li><li><h2><a title="{$c.name}" href="{$c.url}">{$c.name}</a></h2><ul>
{else}

<li><a title="{$c.name}" href="{$c.url}">{$c.name}</a></li>

{/if}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for something along the lines of

```
{foreach from=$sitemap item=c name=sitemap}
    {* open <ul> on first element, only if it is has a parent *}
    {if $smarty.foreach.sitemap.first && $c.parent}<ul>{/if}

    {if !$c.parent}
        {* if this is not the first element, close previous <ul> *}
        {if !$smarty.foreach.sitemap.first}</ul>{/if}
        {* output headline for this <ul> *}
        <h2><a title="{$c.name}" href="{$c.url}">{$c.name}</a></h2>
        {* open new <ul> *}
        <ul>
    {else}
        <li><a title="{$c.name}" href="{$c.url}">{$c.name}</a></li>
    {/if}

    {* close <ul> after last element *}
    {if $smarty.foreach.sitemap.last}</ul>{/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but my mistake as I had not written the complete code from ma program, it also had to display children categories.. Your code worked perfectly to display the parent categories